# Accessing variables in TCL across scopes

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to learn tcl scripting. My req is very simple. I need to access the array "args" in the second if condition in the for loop. I tried the code below. Since "argv" scope is limited to second if condition, it is NOT accessible in for loop

Then I tried declaring argv as global var -

> array set args {}

right below the ned of first if condition. Even after declaring "args" as global array did NOT help.

How do I access the variable in the cope of second if contion, in the for loop below ?

```
if {$argc != 4} {
puts "Insufficient arguments"
exit 1
}

if { $::argc > 0 } {
    set i 1
    foreach arg $::argv {
        puts "argument $i is $arg"
        set args(i) arg
        incr i
        }
} else {
    puts "no command line argument passed"
}

for {set x 0} { $x<2 } {incr x} {
    puts "Arrray: [lindex $args $x]"
}
```

Comment: It's a _very_ good idea to not call a variable `args` unless it is the special final formal argument to a procedure, as that has unusual (but well-documented) semantics and you'll confuse everyone otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your original code, this is the error I get:

```
can't read "args": variable is array
    while executing
"lindex $args $x"
    ("for" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"for {set x 0} { $x<2 } {incr x} {
    puts "Arrray: [lindex $args $x]"
}"
    (file "main.tcl" line 20)
```

In Tcl, arrays are not lists. You have to write

```
for {set x 0} { $x<2 } {incr x} {
    puts "Arrray: $args($x)"
}
```

But then I get this:

```
can't read "args(0)": no such element in array
    while executing
"puts "Arrray: $args($x)""
    ("for" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"for {set x 0} { $x<2 } {incr x} {
    puts "Arrray: $args($x)"
}"
    (file "main.tcl" line 20)
```

Well there's several problems here. You're setting array elements starting with index 1 but reading them starting with index 0. So let's correct that to 0 everywhere:

```
    set i 0
```

But also you're missing some `$`'s in the setting of the elements:

```
        set args($i) $arg
```

That looks better. Final code:

```
if {$argc != 4} {
puts "Insufficient arguments"
exit 1
}

if { $::argc > 0 } {
    set i 0
    foreach arg $::argv {
        puts "argument $i is $arg"
        set args($i) $arg
        incr i
        }
} else {
    puts "no command line argument passed"
}

for {set x 0} { $x<2 } {incr x} {
    puts "Arrray: $args($x)"
}
```

So, scope wasn't quite the issue. You're getting there though!

Answer (score 0):

Tcl does not import globals by default. You need to import your globals:

```
global args
set args(i) arg
```

Some people prefer to import globals at the top of the proc:

```
global args

if {$argc != 4} {
    puts "Insufficient arguments"
    exit 1
}

if { $::argc > 0 } {
    set i 1
    ....
```

See: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/global.htm

Alternatively, you can directly access the global namespace, in fact you're already using that syntax with `::argc`:

```
set ::args(i) arg
```